# Colorbox issue on Android

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I've noticed an issue with Colorbox on Android, where the colorbox popup just hangs with the loading graphic, then if you click to close it, you momentarily see the content (which should have been displayed) in a colorbox popup underneath, then both popups close.

I checked the [official demo on the site](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/) and found the same issue i was experiencing on my own site. The phone I've had the issue on is an HTC Desire running Android Ice Cream Sandwich. The issue doesn't happen with iOS or on Blackberry, seems to be just a weird Android glitch.

Grateful for any help finding a workaround. Mainly flagging this up here as the Colorbox Google Group has been closed.

Comment: Added some more info @blasteralfred

Comment: I can confirm, have noticed the same issue on my Galaxy S3 and Asus TF Prime. Both on my own project as on the official demo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the loading overlay does not get hidden properly after it's done. Luckily that's an easy fix by using the `onComplete` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a.colorbox').colorbox({
        onComplete: function()
        {
            $('#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

This makes sure the loadingOverlay is hidden properly after usage. Colorbox itself will take care of it being reshown. This resolved the issue for my devices.

Let met know if this worked for you too.

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks! The close and prev/next buttons don't show in android now I've noticed, but should be easy enough to find a fix for that.